# flutter create json or add list map

Tags: json, list, flutter

I'm trying to create a custom json and with android java I can use json object and json array, but I couldn't find them in flutter. I created list <Map <String, String >> but when I add data it changes all indexes.

```
    List<Map<String,String>> myList=[];
Map<String,String> mymap;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
mymap['name']='test'+i.toString();
myList.add(mymap);
print(myList[0]);// its always change test0,test1,test2 
}
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
print(myList[i]); // its write test5,test5,test5,test5,test5 why?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign variable to complex class it is passing reference not value, complex classes are those that you created and built in like List, Map ... etc
In this example in your `List` you are adding same `Map` 5 times,
and because it was passing reference same `Map` getting changed 5 times. I hope I make sense.
Here an example.

```
   List<Map<String,String>> myList=[];
   
   Map<String,String> mymap; // This created one object in the current scope.
   
   // First iteration , i = 0  
   mymap['name']='test'+i.toString(); // Now mymap = { name: 'test0' };
   myList.add(mymap); // mylist = [mymap];

   // Second iteration , i = 1
   mymap['name'] = 'test'+i.toString(); // Now mymap = { name: 'test1' };. But since you already added the same mymap in myList, now myList = [{ name: 'test1' }
   myList.add(mymap); // This is again adding the same mymap. So mylist = [{ name: 'test1' }, { name: 'test1' }];
```

Comment: Hi There. Try adding some code and explain it line by line. In it's current state, this might be confusing to OP.

Comment: I added an example, if you run this you can see that after second print `_newMap` value changes, but we do not touch it but rather then `_myMap` has been changed, same thing is with your list, you adding same reference in it 5 times and changing  the map

Comment: Hi. I understand the solution. I was asking you to make your answer more elaborate for the sake of the OP. Let me try and edit your answer for you.

Comment: If you want new value of `Map` you can use `Map.from() ` constructor  which takes another `Map` as parameter

Comment: oh apologies I'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries. I am new as well :D

Answer (score 0):

```
//pass your decoded json
Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(rawJson);

List<Location> locations = List<Location>.from(json["locations"].map((x) => Location.fromJson(x)))
//Location class => days is a premitive list and can be deserialized below
class Location {
  Location({
    this.name,
    this.days,
  });

  String name;
  List<int> days;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
    name: json["name"],
    days: List<int>.from(json["days"].map((x) => x)),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "days": List<dynamic>.from(days.map((x) => x)),
  };
}
```